# Modifying SOAP requests with GetWebRequest

Tags: c#, soap, asmx, soaphttpclientprotocol

I am trying to dynamically modify XML data in SOAP requests to ASMX services.

I overrided `GetWebRequest()` method in `SoapHttpClientProtocol` class in order to read and modify XML data that the `RequestStream` contains.

The problem is, the request seems to be empty, there is no data in it whatsoever. Is this because the SOAP data hasn't yet been generated and serialized or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Most likely, have you tried overriding [GetWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8415zzb7.aspx) instead?

Comment: Nope, it's GetWebRequest. Maybe my understanding of the method is flawed though... is it possible that it occurs before the actual SOAP data is set? It would certainly seem that way.

Comment: My interpretation of the documentation was that GetWebRequest would return an empty web request (for a given url) to be populated.  The GetWebResponse method is then called in order to get the actual response after the request object has been "populated" with the SOAP request body, so this would be the place to modify it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is the correct method after all, the request object is already fully populated when the method enters. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `SoapExtension`. You could hook into the `SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize` stage in `ProcessMessage` to modify your soap message. I've done this in the past to add WSSE headers in situations where I couldn't add a dependency on Microsoft's WSE library (since it isn't available for Mono).

Complete tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164007.aspx

`GetWebRequest` is too early for your purpose, `GetWebResponse` is too late.